# warning ... defined but not used - do I really need .c file?

Tags: c, gcc, static, header, inline

I find out that Apple uses the following declaration in OSAtomic.h header:

```
inline static int32_t   OSAtomicDecrement32( volatile int32_t *__theValue )
            { return OSAtomicAdd32( -1, __theValue); }
```

I am getting the following warning when including it and compiling:

```
warning: 'int32_t OSAtomicDecrement32(volatile int32_t*)' defined but not used
```

That is true, but I would like to know answers to the following:

1. Do they really need to have this symbol defined in some library (to get rid of this warning)? If the function OSAtomicDecrement32 can be created only by calling OSAtomicAdd32, why one can't define this in a header directly? Should they use #define OSAtomicDecrement32 ...body.. instead?
2. If I don't call OSAtomicDecrement32 in my program, why does it complain that symbol OSAtomicAdd32 is undefined (when I don't link with a library which defines it)? It is inline, I thought that when I don't use something, the compiler would strip it off...

Thanks for explaining it to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the reason for gcc complaining about this is the `static` keyword which results in code for this function to be emitted in any compilation unit. They just shouldn't do it like this. Either they'd use

- clear C99 standard code. Then they'd just have to do `inline` without
  `static` and provide the symbol in just one library, libc e.g.
- use compiler extensions like gcc's (and thus clang's) attribute
  `always_inline`

but never `static`.

BTW, gcc has extension for this operations (prefixed with `__sync` IIRC) that would be portable to other systems where there is gcc, clang, icc, opencc...

Perhaps you could get around this by adding some arguments to the gcc call. Try `-std=c99` or switch off the corresponding warning.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! In case they used one of your proposed ideas, where would the body of this function be? In the aforementioned header or in a library? If in a library, will inline cause the code from the library to be inlined or this does this function always have to be called?

Comment: Without the `static` it would all be fine in the header, I think. With a standard conforming compiler they'd just have to put an `extern` *declaration* in one compilation unit to have a replacement symbol generated for the (here) unlikely case that sometimes the function can't be inlined in one of its users.

Answer (score 0):

The warning message doesn't say that `OSAtomicDecrement32` is undefined, quite the opposite. The message is telling you that there is a function that is defined but you do not call it. If it's from an external library there is nothing to worry about, and if it's in your own code then maybe you just haven't written the code to call it yet.

Comment: Right, but even when I didn't use it (didn't call it) and doesn't provide a library which implements OSAtomicAdd32 while linking, it won't link explaining that OSAtomicAdd32 is undefined...

Comment: @kexik It's not an error. If it doesn't link it's because of some other error.